# ngx-mask don't work properly after updateValueAndValidity on the input control, angular 11

Tags: angular, ngx-mask

I have an input using the ngx-mask 
`<input type="text" [mask]="maskPhoneFormat" formControlName="contactPhone" />`
In the ts file I use:
 `this.contactPopupForm.get('contactPhone')?.updateValueAndValidity();`
 because I change the Validator for that Input, after that the ngx-mask ("*requiredMask*") stop working on that input, any ideas?

I create a stackblitz with example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lf8e1s?file=src/app/app.component.html 
The first time you introduce the phone number works good, after introducing a name and editing the phone number again, the ngx-mask doesn't works properly

Comment: Do you have a stackblitz link for this issue?

Comment: @Jimmy no, but I can do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just replace `setValidators` by `addValidators`.

The difference is: `add` will `append` new validators. `set` will `replace` the current with new validators

Same goes with `removeValidators` and `clearValidators`